# Не хочет придавать значение переменной, random импортирован

Tags: python, python-3.x

> aleft = random.randint(10, 361)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in 
aleft = random.randint(10, 361)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'randint'

> aleft = (random.randint(10, 361))

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#30>", line 1, in 
aleft = (random.randint(10, 361))
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'randint'

Comment: Приведите [mre]

Comment: Возможно вы импортировали ```random``` так ```from random import random```. Если да то интерпритатор говорит, что ```random``` это не модуль а функция.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А не нужно давать своим функциям имена импортируемых модулей! Где-то выше в коде создана функция `random()` примерно так:

```
def random():
```

Вот её и нужно переименовать.